# Expression evaluation inside the while loop

Tags: c, while-loop, expression

How many times CppBuzz.com is printed?

```
   int main()
    {
      int a = 0;
      while(a++ < 5-++a)
      printf("CppBuzz.com");
      return 0;
     }
```

how to solve the expression (5-++a) ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a bigger problem than determining loop counter in your code - [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The line

```
  while(a++ < 5-++a)
```

tries to increment the same variable `a` more than once without a sequence point, it invokes undefined behavior.

That said, if you don't want any conversion specification to happen, don't use `printf()`, use `puts()` instead.

Comment: With the GCC compiler, the statement gets printed even if a has undefined behavior. How is this possible?

Comment: @PadmaR Please note that [undefined](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) doesn't necessarily mean "it won't work".

Answer (score 1):

Code invoked undefined behaviour. Here multiple time variable `a` increments.

GCC Compiler generates warning:

```
prog.c: In function 'main':
prog.c:8:21: warning: operation on 'a' may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]
       while(a++ < 5-++a)
                     ^~~
```